# C# .NET Core 2.2 Web Api ~ upload file as stream does not work

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to **upload a file es stream using REST**.
I implement the code like I find at [dotnetcoretutorials.com](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/12/uploading-files-asp-net-core/), which looks quit good.
And than I add a *index.htm* inside my project folder:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" id="myfile"/>  
    <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile();" value="Upload" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadFile() {        
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                 
    var file = document.getElementById('myfile').files[0];
    xhr.open("POST", "api/upload");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("filename", file.name);
    xhr.send(file);
}
```

I start the project with IIS and call the index.html in my browser. I choose a file and click the "Update" -button. The chosen file is not copied anywhere.

**Why the upload does not work?**

The file myfile.temp is not written. I get this exception:

> index.html:11 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/frank.mehlhop/source/repos/FileTransfer/FileTransfer/wwwroot/api/upload' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I tried at the cmd

> .\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files file:///C:\Users\frankmehlhop\source\repos\FileTransfer\FileTransfer\wwwroot\index.html

, but no changes. At my breakpoints the code does not stop, when I start my App, the breakpoints are marked yellow with

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

UploadController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileTransfer.Controllers
{
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/upload")]
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2#uploading-large-files-with-streaming
    // https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/12/uploading-files-asp-net-core/

    [HttpPost]
    [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        FormValueProvider formModel;
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create("c:\\temp\\myfile.temp"))
        {
            formModel = await Request.StreamFile(stream);
        }

        var viewModel = new MyViewModel();

        var bindingSuccessful = await TryUpdateModelAsync(viewModel, prefix: "",
           valueProvider: formModel);

        if (!bindingSuccessful)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }

        return Ok(viewModel);
    }

    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

FileStreamHelper.cs

```
public static class FileStreamingHelper
{
    private static readonly FormOptions _defaultFormOptions = new FormOptions();

    public static async Task<FormValueProvider> StreamFile(this HttpRequest request, Stream targetStream)
    {
        if (!MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(request.ContentType))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Expected a multipart request, but got {request.ContentType}");
        }

        // Used to accumulate all the form url encoded key value pairs in the 
        // request.
        var formAccumulator = new KeyValueAccumulator();
        string targetFilePath = null;

        var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
            MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(request.ContentType),
            _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
        var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body);

        var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
        while (section != null)
        {
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition;
            var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition, out contentDisposition);

            if (hasContentDispositionHeader)
            {
                if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFileContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
                {
                    await section.Body.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
                }
                else if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFormDataContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
                {
                    // Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"
                    //
                    // value

                    // Do not limit the key name length here because the 
                    // multipart headers length limit is already in effect.
                    var key = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(contentDisposition.Name);
                    var encoding = GetEncoding(section);
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(
                        section.Body,
                        encoding,
                        detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true,
                        bufferSize: 1024,
                        leaveOpen: true))
                    {
                        // The value length limit is enforced by MultipartBodyLengthLimit
                        var value = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                        if (String.Equals(value, "undefined", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            value = String.Empty;
                        }
                        formAccumulator.Append(key.Value, value); // For .NET Core <2.0 remove ".Value" from key

                        if (formAccumulator.ValueCount > _defaultFormOptions.ValueCountLimit)
                        {
                            throw new InvalidDataException($"Form key count limit {_defaultFormOptions.ValueCountLimit} exceeded.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Drains any remaining section body that has not been consumed and
            // reads the headers for the next section.
            section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
        }

        // Bind form data to a model
        var formValueProvider = new FormValueProvider(
            BindingSource.Form,
            new FormCollection(formAccumulator.GetResults()),
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        return formValueProvider;
    }

    private static Encoding GetEncoding(MultipartSection section)
    {
        MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType;
        var hasMediaTypeHeader = MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentType, out mediaType);
        // UTF-7 is insecure and should not be honored. UTF-8 will succeed in 
        // most cases.
        if (!hasMediaTypeHeader || Encoding.UTF7.Equals(mediaType.Encoding))
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8;
        }
        return mediaType.Encoding;
    }
}
```

DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute.cs

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        var formValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
            .OfType<FormValueProviderFactory>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (formValueProviderFactory != null)
        {
            context.ValueProviderFactories.Remove(formValueProviderFactory);
        }

        var jqueryFormValueProviderFactory = context.ValueProviderFactories
            .OfType<JQueryFormValueProviderFactory>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (jqueryFormValueProviderFactory != null)
        {
            context.ValueProviderFactories.Remove(jqueryFormValueProviderFactory);
        }
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

MultipartRequestHelper.cs

```
public static class MultipartRequestHelper
{
    // Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="----WebKitFormBoundarymx2fSWqWSd0OxQqq"
    // The spec says 70 characters is a reasonable limit.
    public static string GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, int lengthLimit)
    {
        var boundary = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(contentType.Boundary).ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(boundary))
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException("Missing content-type boundary.");
        }

        if (boundary.Length > lengthLimit)
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException(
                $"Multipart boundary length limit {lengthLimit} exceeded.");
        }

        return boundary;
    }

    public static bool IsMultipartContentType(string contentType)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType)
               && contentType.IndexOf("multipart/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }

    public static bool HasFormDataContentDisposition(ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition)
    {
        // Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key";
        return contentDisposition != null
               && contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals("form-data")
               && string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName.ToString())
               && string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileNameStar.ToString());
    }

    public static bool HasFileContentDisposition(ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition)
    {
        // Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile1"; filename="Misc 002.jpg"
        return contentDisposition != null
               && contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals("form-data")
               && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName.ToString())
                   || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileNameStar.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: The file should appear in the file c:\\temp\\myfile.temp. Do you see a file there? Can the webserver write there? Does the folder C:\\ temp exist? My debugging workflow would be: 1) What error do you get when using the webdevelopment toolbar? Is there any response? Is it 200?. 2) What can you find when debugging your app?

Comment: Hi Arend, I include my answer to your questions into my initial text.